# Visual Studio 2019 Break points not being hit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

Break points in my project is not working in Visual Studio 2019.

What I tried so far:

1. My project is in Debug mode, I checked.
2. Debug > Attach to Process > w3wp.ex
3. Enabling Properties > Web tab > Debuggers > ASP.NET
4. Unchecking the Properties > Build > Optimize Code
5. Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio
6. Enabling "Managed Compatibility Mode" by going to Tools -> Options -> Debugging.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but it has happened to me before. Did you check whether you're attaching to the correct process (ie: some other process hidden behind the show all processes)?

Comment: Are you debug files deployed current as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Could you please explain more?